# change days count of month in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jalali-calendar

for some reasons i would like to change days count of a mooon in jquery ui datepicker library. means all month of the year should have 31 days. the jquery ui datepicker library has a function named _getDaysInMonth:

```
_getDaysInMonth:function(a,b){32-this._daylightSavingAdjust(new Date(a,b,32)).getDate()}
```

i changed it to:

```
_getDaysInMonth:function(a,b){return 31;}
```

i changed it to return '31' value everytime. but still some month has 30 and 28 days.
how can i change it? thanks...

Comment: You would probably need to write your own datepicker for this that doesn't rely on using javascript Date object

Comment: looking into the library, this line :- `printDate.setDate(printDate.getDate() + 1);` will not allow what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can make a function that takes the number of days in a month and then appends on to the it days until it is 31. There are all sorts of problems in doing this. Could you explain why you want all month to have 31 days?